# Website Connection to Local MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I have recently configured a MySQL server on my Windows home computer. In addition, I have also created a website using 0fees.net-- a free hosting provider which comes with a vista panel that has various services including PHP support, FTP file-hosting, its own MySQL server etc.

For that website, I have created a "login" PHP script in order for people to login to my webpage. However, instead of reading from the MySQL database given to me on the cPanel on 0fees.net, I want the PHP logon script to read directly from the MySQL server that I have configured on my home computer. To do this, I have taken several steps:

1) Configured MySQL using the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard

In that configuration, I have enabled TCP/IP Networking on port 3306 (and enabled a firewall exception for that port) and have enabled root access from remote machines.

2) On the MySQL command-line-client, I have granted remote access capabilities to other units by using:

```
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

3) I have forwarded port 3306 to my router (and have used various port checkers to confirm that it is open)

4) I have created the login script called "login.php" which lies in my site's .htdocs directory and that process an HTML login form on the homepage of my website. It attempts (and fails) to connect to my local MySQL server. The segment of interest of that php script is:

```
    $host="my_external_ip:3306"; // External IP of my computer and port to listen on
    $username="root"; // Username specified in the GRANT command-line-client command
    $password="password"; // Password specified in the GRANT command-line-client command
    $db_name="logon"; // MySQL database name
    $tbl_name="accounts"; // Table name within the database

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

When attempting to connect to the MySQL sever, I get an error message that states:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my_external_ip' (4).
```

It should also be noted that I am successfully able to connect to my local MySQL server remotely from other machines which are on other internet networks (tested with Navicat) using this same external IP address on port 3306. Any ideas as to why my website cannot also connect?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Well I can tell you that your port is definitely open and listening (bad idea posting your IP like that).

Comment: Also, it's good practice to create a different user than root for connections coming from php... You should create a new user with restricted privileges for your php connections

Comment: Is there a proxy between your site and your local?

Answer (score 3):

Since I can tell that your server is definitely running (and visible from the internets in general), there are a few possibilities:

1. You forgot to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`
2. Your username or password are wrong
3. Your free host provider is blocking the connection

My money is on #3, there are a lot of incentives to do that.

Comment: #3 is exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Thanks, right now I'm using a free website hosting service. However, if I upgrade, I can use an Access Host feature to enable remote connections. Will this do the trick? (assuming that is the cause)

Comment: @user797967: your guess is as good as mine (probably better). I don't know anything about that hosting provider. From a hosting point of view, it's preferable to have your customers use *your* database, because then you can charge them out the ass for each additional DB (plus there's the whole security aspect).

Answer (score 0):

@Chris mentioned that your provider might be blocking outbound requests on port 3306.  Here's a quick way to check if that's the case and get around it:

1. Configure your router to port forward from port 80 on the router to port 3306 on your box.  This will allow you to connect to MySQL from outside your network on port 80 instead of port 3306.
2. Change your PHP code to connect to your IP on port 80 instead of 3306.

Your hosting provider might block outbound port 3306, but the almost certainly wouldn't block outbound port 80 requests (lots of people using CURL or web services and such).

Comment: @Eric Petroelje thanks for the insight but I'm not sure I'm fully understanding step 1.

Comment: @user - you mention that you have "forwarded port 3306 to my router (and have used various port checkers to confirm that it is open)".  That's the step you need to change.  In the port forwarding settings for your router, you would need to specify that connections on port 80 should be forwarded to port 3306 on your MySQL box (rather than forwarding 3306 -> 3306 you are now forwarding 80 -> 3306).  Hope that clears it up a bit

Comment: @Eric Petroelje- yes it did, thank you very much, i'll try this right now

Comment: @Eric Petroelje- Sorry, I don't know how to redirect connections on port 80 to port 3306 in my router configuration.

Comment: @user - if forwarding from one port to another isn't possible (not all routers support it) you could modify mysql to run on port 80 instead of 3306, then set up the router to forward port 80.  Note that port 80 is typically used for web servers, so if you have IIS or Apache running on your box, mysql won't be able to start on port 80.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje- Thanks once again. I guess I'll need a different router for this =P as I get a "Port Range Overlap with Remote Management" error when trying to forward port 80.

Comment: Is it possible that I can try to see if there are other ports where outbound requests are not blocked and forward/configure MySQL to those?

Comment: @user - yup, that's certainly a possibility.  I would probably start with some of the better known ports (say 21 or 22 for ftp/sftp) as they are less likely to be blocked.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje- Thanks, I'll try forwarding them as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Well I will let you in on a little trick I learned, all you got to do is go into `wamp>mysql>my.ini` and replace all `3306` with `3305` then save and then apply this to your firewall and port forward `3305`. Then when you are connecting remotely, simply do

```
mysql_connect("ip adress:3305", "username", "password");
```

I've tested this and it works because the web hosting sites block incoming traffic from port 3306.